# How can I use SQL Server classes (e.g. SqlCommand) to prevent SQL injection WITHOUT database connection?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-injection

I am currently checking StackOverflow for best practices about preventing SQL injection using C# code, and many of the answers include .NET SQL classes, like `SqlCommand`, `SqlDataAdapter`, ...

The problem is that I have to use a proprietary middleware component to send the query to the database, and I can't find any way to use those classes without using a `SqlConnection`.

Here is my example code:

```
SqlCommand sqlC = new SqlCommand("USP_MyProcedure");
sqlC.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
sqlC.Parameters.AddWithValue("@strRef", strRef);
sqlC.Parameters.AddWithValue("@strCmd", strCmd);
sqlC.Parameters.AddWithValue("@strParam", strParam);
sqlC.Parameters.AddWithValue("@strDef", strDef);
sqlC.Parameters.AddWithValue("@strWn", sWn);
```

The `SqlCommand` seems properly initialized, the `SqlParameterCollection` seems OK, but the property `SqlC.CommandText` returns only "USP_MyProcedure".

If I use other classes to deal with my `SqlCommand`, for example:

```
SqlDataReader reader = sqlC.ExecuteReader();
```

I get an error because I have no connection to use:

> The connection property has to be initialized

So, my questions are:

- Is there a way to use those .NET classes (or others?) to prepare my SQL queries to prevent SQL injections?
- If not, are there other .NET classes to prevent SQL injections or do I have to implement myself anti-SQL injection methods? Based on which best practice from your point of view?

EDIT: looks like I have misunderstood how those classes work.

Those classes do not prepare SQL statements "offline" and are designed to be used with a SqlConnection.

But I can change the question to ask it from another point of view: **are there .NET classes to prepare SQL statements "offline" against injection?**

Comment: Sounds somewhat like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) to me.

Comment: I'm a bit confused - are you saying that your "middleware" only supports text SQL queries and not commands with parameters?

Comment: So do I understand you correctly? You are wanting to use `SqlCommand` to produce the SQL query that you can then send to this middleware?

Comment: @DStanley yes, that is correct

Comment: @MattBurland yes, exactly

Comment: I think you misunderstand how the prevention of SQL Injection works; these classes **WILL NOT** "prepare" a SQL statement, as in taking a SQL statement and replacing the parameter placeholders with actual values. Instead - the **parametrized** query (**including** parameter placeholders) and a list of parameters is sent to SQL Server - and only the **server** will then combine the two. So the `SqlCommand` **DOES NOT** take the SQL statement text and replace parameters with values ..... so you cannot really use these classes "offline" for anything....

Comment: @marc_s thanks, I see I have misunderstood the role of those classes. I edited my post to change my question to focus on preparing SQL statements "offline"

Comment: The middleware should do this for you, or provide an interface to do it. If neither is true, it's garbage.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson It's garbage then :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`SqlCommand` is designed to work with `SqlConnection` to specifically query MS SQL Server - it is not designed to be a "generic" SQL command that works against any middleware or arbitrary providers that use their own connection methods. Nor can you use it to generically "prepare" text SQL commands.

Your middleware should provide its own command/connection types if it's meant to be compatible with ADO.NET. If it does not, then you may be stuck with text queries and concatenating strings, and need to find other ways to protect against SQL Injection (scrubbing comment markers, escaping quotes, etc.)

> are there .NET classes to prepare SQL statements "offline" against injection?

No.